# Can I begin roleplaying if I'm visually impaired?

Tags: new-players, online-roleplaying, accessibility

I've been reading about RPGs for a long time, and I'm extremely interested in trying it... But I'm afraid to start because I'm visually impaired and have to use a screen reader to navigate a screen. RPGs seem very complicated and I think I'd really love the actual voice roleplaying of the characters, but I'm scared of the rules and the dice rolling and all that.

I'm mostly concerned about having a slower reaction time than other players, since I need to run through new information with the help of a narrator. I don't want to always be the person the GM has to explain things to.

Can someone explain to me whether or not I can actually do this, and how to get started?

Please note: This is for online voice chat roleplaying. I don't think I'd be able to physically go to a comic store or anything to roleplay each week.

Comment: Speaking of accessibility, Shalvenay's related link: [GMing for blind and visually impaired players](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/6532/gming-for-disabled-players-specifically-blind-players)

Comment: If you are roleplaying on the computer and need a dice rolling app that works with screen readers (I'm using NVDA), here is a link I found: https://dicelog.com/dice

Comment: Even though everything has been answered very thoroughly, I thought I'd add in a comment about the [Going In Blind podcast](http://goinginblindpodcast.com/) which sought to do exactly this with D&D 5e. This was a group of visually impaired players out of Australia who recorded their sessions and then went back and added in all sorts of neat sound effects to increase the immersion. I used to listen to it on my morning commute to gain ideas for sessions. I'm not related to the project in any way; I'm not even sure if it's still active - I just thought it would be interesting for people to see wh

Answer (score 61, accepted):

### TL;DR: To accommodate for the visual parts of roleplaying, either abolish them or prepare for them in advance. The majority of roleplaying is oral. You can do that.

I've now been playing RPGs for 2 months now.

I can now say wholeheartedly: **Yes, roleplaying if you are visually impaired is possible.**

This is entirely subjective, so I'll list out my background:

1. **I am not fully blind.** I am incapable of reading words, but can still see colors and navigate a screen decently well.
2. **I am very familiar with navigating my computer.** I think this gives me a major advantage. I have a moderately quick response time.
3. **I use a screen reader to read text to me.** I use [NVDA](http://www.nvaccess.org/). I have no clue how other screen readers work. If you are using a magnifier and that works for you, I think you have an even easier time than someone who needs a screen reader.
4. **I am only playing online via voice chat.** I still have no experience with playing in-person and don't think I can. The process might be entirely different.

This is my conclusion in the 3 months since I asked this question: **No matter your level of visual impairment, if you're savvy enough with your computer, I think you'll be fine.** If you can find & read this post, I think you're well enough on your way to be able to play RPGs.

My goal with roleplaying was to not be a burden on the other players. I wanted them to feel like I'm just a new player rather than a visually impaired new player. I wanted to be able to keep up with the action without people going out of their way to accommodate for the fact that I'm disabled. I think I've accomplished this well enough.

Here's what made it possible...

### Before Playing The Game

#### You need lots of preparation time.

1. **Read the manual, maybe multiple times.** Get a PDF manual of the game and read it however you can. (I use [NaturalReader, free PDF-to-speech](http://naturalreaders.com/index.html).) This is hard. This is genuinely hard. PDFs aren't usually accessibility-friendly. There are multiple columns that read in the wrong order & plenty of images to throw you off. So, read it multiple times, take notes in any way that helps you retain that information, try to understand it as well as you possibly can before your game. The goal here is to be on as even of a ground as possible as someone who read it in the way it was meant to be read.
2. **Take the time to translate your Character Sheet PDF to a text file.** I tried an Excel sheet, it just didn't work as well for me as a plain text file. I've uploaded my Character Sheet for my Dungeon World Paladin [here](http://pastebin.com/giQbFwJZ). I'm aware that Dungeon World is a relatively simple game, but I think with the right amount of preparation, this could work with any game. Character Creation seems to be the most difficult thing. You're going to be referencing this file all the time. It took a while for me to make beforehand, but it's seamless during actual gameplay.
3. **Make sure the game is being played in a way that works for you.** There's two aspects to this: 1) Are you okay with the game system? and 2) Are you okay with the method of play? You need a concrete yes to both of these before committing.

You'll have to figure out what game systems work for you on your own time. Try reading the game's manual & seeing if it fits your playstyle. If this is your first game and you don't know if it fits your playstyle yet, try any of the systems recommended in the answers below. I've played Dungeon World/Fate Accelerated/Roll For Shoes with great success.

Personally, I think D&D and especially AD&D are way too advanced if this is your first time. This has little to do with your visual impairment and more to do with being a new player in general. It's hard to keep up with a ton of mechanics for any new player, so games that are easier to pick up for new players are naturally easier for visually impaired new players. If you want to play something more mechanical down the road, it's perfectly possible. I just wouldn't recommend it first off.

#### You need a method of gameplay (that works with a screen reader).

This is tough. This is what separates games that I can play and games that I can't play. Again, I'm playing primarily by voice chat and I use a screen reader most of the time.

I tried Roll20 and Rolz.org. They did not really work for me. Both are completely incompatible with my screen reader.

Skype or Hangouts would probably work fine. I don't know how people using Skype handle dice. I know that Hangouts has some RPG-friendly extensions that people use. I don't know if those extensions are accessibility-friendly. [Here](https://dicelog.com/dice) is an online dice roller that is accessibility-friendly. I think Skype/Hangouts is perfectly possible as long as you have a test session with a friendly person to iron out the kinks.

I've used Discord and I love it. There's TTS right in the settings, dice bots that work perfectly once you get them set up, and cross-platform voice chat. Discord has been extremely pleasant and allows me to just have one app to fulfill every aspect of the game. I can be up and ready to go in 5 minutes.

The major issue is simply that you will have a larger learning curve than someone who has visual access. I think every platform except Roll20 is *technically* possible to play on. It's just going to take some time to learn and navigate around.

#### You need a friendly & patient group of people to play with.

I've considered joining games and not telling the people involved that I am visually impaired. Personally, I'm very shameful of it & I delude myself into thinking mentioning it is a cry for help. You should tell your fellow players that you're visually impaired. This has little to do with asking for help. You need to tell them so they can relate to you as a person better, and in case a hiccup occurs during a session and you just need a few minutes to get your bearings.

I feel confident enough to be able to approach any campaign group after spending a few months with a very nice group. But, without that first good impression, I probably would have quit the hobby completely. If you don't know where to go to find a group (I didn't, and somewhat still don't) head to the StackExchange RPG Chat. People are very nice there and can point you in the right direction, or even invite you to join their group.

First impressions are extremely important. I was very stressed the first month of the campaign, to the point where I considered ditching the first gameplay session and never coming back. So, try to find friendly & accommodating people. It makes all the difference in how enjoyable & stress-free your experience is. Talk to them before agreeing to a long-term campaign with them.

### During The Game

This is the part none of the other answers prepared me for. There's one key problem with roleplaying as a visually impaired person:

#### While everyone else is using their hearing to follow along with the other players and using their vision to reference their character sheet and the manual...but you have to accomplish both of these with just your hearing.

I don't really know a way around this. This is always going to make roleplaying harder for you than other people.

The only thing that can reduce the stress of this is to be as prepared as possible. If I already know what moves are available to me and how they work, I don't need to use my hearing to flip back to the manual and can spend most of my time listening to everyone else and following along with the group's flow.

If you only need to make occasional references, the only time you'll have your screen reader interrupt everyone else is to hear the results of a roll. People are normally quiet for a few seconds while waiting for the result anyway, so I found this didn't interrupt the gameplay.

By the second gameplay session, I felt pretty similar to everyone else because I only had my TTS interrupt everyone else when a roll occured. I could devote my brain energy to being creative rather than flipping back to the manual and hearing my screen reader slowly narrate to me and talking over all the other players.

### Ask for a character creation session and a separate first gameplay session.

In Dungeon World, a game that's relatively light in the character creation department, I was unable to complete my character creation in the 2 hours we were all talking. I just couldn't keep up with listening to everyone develop the setting and filling out the mechanics of my character at the same time. That required way too much manual referencing & text file formatting.

I took the week between the character creation session and the first gameplay session to take my time and finish my character. I really found I needed to do this on my own time, at my own pace.

If your group is doing character creation and gameplay on the same day, talk to your GM and see if you can schedule something one-on-one beforehand to make your character before everyone else does.

#### Try to avoid games that require maps.

We couldn't figure out a way to make this work in the gameplay. It's not required in games like DW, Fate, etc.. I already think it takes a huge frontload of work to participate in RPGs as a visually impaired person, and you really don't need the extra stress.

...

This is all I found that was an impediment in the gameplay. Every other issue was related to being a new player in general (character development, choosing a playstyle). After a certain point, there was no difference between me being a new player vs. being a *visually impaired* new player.

It's very possible. I found the preparation to be drudgery, but when playing  in a real-time improvisational environment... I had loads of fun. I think it's worth the drudgery. It's an extremely creative outlet that has a lot less barriers for someone who is visually impaired than other outlets.

**Remember, at its core, roleplaying, especially through real-time voice chat, is mostly oral storytelling.** You can already do that! All you have to do is take the time to work around the logistics.

(Special thanks to [nitsua60](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/23970/nitsua60), [BESW](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/4398/besw), [Shalvenay](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/16044/shalvenay), and [Sandwich](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/14949/sandwich).)

Comment: Answer in your own answers folks.

Answer (score 118):

### Absolutely

Here's the bare minimum you need to successfully join the roleplaying hobby:

- At least one other willing person
- Mutual communication

That's it, full stop.

The complexity and bar to entry into RPGs don't have to be high — as evidence, I give you *any five year old I've ever met*. Seriously, the way children develop social skills is through social play. If you can communicate well enough with someone to hypothesize a world and people in it, you can role play with them. I know this because I spent about two years playing D&D with some deaf friends via an interpreter.

Adults tend to be a bit more demanding in the fields of "fairness" and "verisimilitude". When they play roleplaying games, they add rules. At a guess, you've heard of D&D. To give you one end of the spectrum, some of the older versions feature about 600-800 pages of core rules and thousands of pages of optional material. It also requires a set of polyhedral dice (or an online roller). Optional gear includes a battle mat and some mini figures. Painted ones are nice, but I've used everything down to pieces of candy.

On the other side of the spectrum, you can find a variety of games that break [any given assumption](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/24721/what-is-a-trad-game). For example, [Roll For Shoes](https://rollforshoes.com/) has six rules, which fit on an index card. It requires only "normal" six-sided die, like you'd find in Monopoly or other traditional board games. Other systems throw out ideas like needing dice (the Amber Diceless RPG), or having a GM at all.

So, the only remaining question given your communication constraints is where you can find an online group to play a voice chat with. One option to check out is [this site's built-in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11/trpg-general-chat).

---

The above is rooted in my own opinion and experiences with the RPG hobby. I am not the only one with similar thoughts. In the 5th edition D&D player's handbook, the preface is written by one of the two lead designers, Mike Mearls. Excerpt [snip]'ed for brevity, he says this:

> To play D&D, and to play it well, you don't need to read all the rules, memorize every detail of the game, or master the fine art of rolling funny looking dice. None of those things have any bearing on what's best about the game.
>
> What you need are two things, the first being friends with whom you can share the game. [snip]
>
> D&D is an exercise in collaborative creation. [snip]
>
> [snip]
>
> The second thing you need is a lively imagination or, more importantly, the willingness to use whatever imagination you have.

---

I also stumbled upon a website for a group that specifically claims to be a community of several hundred people with the goal of supporting blind, visually impaired, and sighted people in the tabletop roleplaying hobby. It appears they have a reasonably active blog (as of March 2023) as well as accessibility resources for specific games. If they can play, so can you. https://knightsofthebraille.com/

Comment: You can even roleplay without "At least one other willing person," provided you accept that games like *Hikikomori RPG* count as RPGs. Most games do require multiple participants, though.

Comment: How not visually impaired five years old is related?

Comment: @enkryptor It seemed to me that the querent's big concern is how RPGs are big and complicated, and he wasn't sure if he could keep up. The crux of my answer is that the bar for role playing is so low that children do it naturally. The bulk of the rest of the answer is demonstrating the wide variety of complexity you can find in RPGs. OP just needs to pick one that's on the simpler side of the spectrum and find people to play with.

Comment: @enkryptor Most five year olds can't read or write to the degree of reliability or proficiency necessary to consume a manual or fill out a character sheet. They are, as I can attest personally, able to roleplay. I came home last night and found that my 5 year old who I knew her whole life as Grace was actually Ceska, Princess of the Fairy World. I'd say you can't make this up, but she actually did.

Comment: Anecdotally, I had a blind DM for several months.

Comment: A good GM should have no problem assisting you where reading is necessary (or would speed things along); introducing you to the mechanics of the system, helping you build a character, etc. During gameplay, if the GM has a copy of your character sheet, he/she may be able to look up and tell you what you need to roll, if that speeds up gameplay.

Comment: If you're using voice chat, I'd recommend headphones -- if you need to message the GM some private info, or the GM needs to share character-specific info (e.g. you make a spot check that the others don't), this will probably be done via text chat, and it could spoil things if the other players hear your screen reader rattling off what the GM just messaged you!

Comment: @Zymus On the one hand, I don't think your comment contributes to or critiques this answer very well, so I'm not sure why you posted it here. On the other hand, it sounds like you've got good experience with this specifically, and I look forward to you expanding on that with your own answer.

Answer (score 44):

## Yes, this is definitely doable.

1. First, there are RPGs that aren't that complicated and/or don't require dice. Consider skipping GURPS and Burning Wheel in favor of simpler ones like Microscope, Risus, FATE, etc. (We don't do specific game recommendations here, just because it doesn't work well with the site format, but if you're able to use the chat room, folks can offer suggestions.)
2. Even if you play a "standard" game with more rules (DND is the most enduringly popular), most of the complexity in most games I can think of is around the character creation process. There's not a ton of looking at the rulebooks during play in most groups. The standard flow is: Gamemaster describes a scene or situation. Players describe their actions. GM describes the result of their actions. It's fundamentally a verbal activity. So while it may be extra work, if you can use a screen reader with a PDF of the rules to familiarize yourself in advance, it definitely shouldn't be insurmountable. (Since many games have mechanisms for improving your character, you'll want a group that's either led by someone friendly who can talk you through the process each time - pretty common with newbies anyway - and/or levels up in between sessions, so there's less time pressure around reading and writing.)
3. Character sheets could be tricky. I don't know if you'd be able to use a large-format or fillable PDF sheet, or not. A text file might work, but there's an argument for picking a less complex game that doesn't require keeping track of a dozen things on a character sheet. However, many games require you to keep track of something - hit points, fate points, whatever - so you may need to find a tactile way to do that (stacking cubes?) or else keep a separate text or calculator window open with just that number as you update it.
4. Games that are heavily dependent on a battle map are probably out, but this is optional at most, and difficult to pull off over the net without special tools, so especially since you're playing online it shouldn't be a big deal. Just something to be aware of.
5. Dice, fortunately, should be no problem. Any online rpg group should have a way to roll dice online; the one my group uses is [rolz.org](http://www.rolz.org), but there are many more.

## How to get started

That's a pretty big question. Fortunately, others have covered various aspects of getting started with RPGs on this very site; check out the [new-players](/questions/tagged/new-players) tag to browse, or try searching for your specific concerns. For starters, check out [Finding online RPG players for a play-by-chat RPG Campaign?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/18665/finding-online-rpg-players-for-a-play-by-chat-rpg-campaign)

Comment: Many online games use things like MapTools/Roll20/etc to play using virtual tabletops/battlemaps. I'd recommend the O.P. try one of those out solo (just run it up, load  a map, try moving some tokens around) and that will help them judge whether those sort of games will work for them.

Comment: I feel that Microscope is a bad recommendation for a visually impaired player.  While it's very simple, it's also very visual in a way that does not screenread well.  Fate is a better choice.

Comment: Another recommendation could be the SHERPA RPG. It's made to be played on the trail, so without character sheets or looking at other players. I haven't played it with a blind person, though, so there could be problems I'm overlooking.

Answer (score 27):

My experience says it works fine.

I was in a gaming group a few years ago that had a player who was losing his sight; by the last time I played with him, he was effectively totally blind -- he used a screen reader, had PDF files of the rules books he needed, used a computer character generator or spreadsheet that worked with his screen reader.  We were playing face to face, but it would work the same way via chat, except that another player can't help instantly if your computer develops a problem during the game or between games.

During the time I knew him, we also introduced his wife, who was partially sighted, to gaming (with GURPS, no less; 500+ pages of core rules and a deserved reputation for complexity, though it can be dialed back if the players and GM choose).  Generally, being new to gaming will be a larger factor than visual limitations, and other players are virtually always happy to accommodate having to be told what to roll and when as needed while you internalize the game's mechanics.

If you were formerly sighted, you'll probably have no trouble visualizing the situations, though you'll have to play Theater of the Mind even if others are using miniatures (unless you have enough vision to check your miniature movements via video chat).  Beyond that, I'd recommend reading the player portion of the core rules for your chosen game at least once (more, if you need to), so you understand the game mechanics before you start.  That won't make you proficient, but it'll give you the grounding to become proficient more quickly.  Depending on the chosen game, there may be free or paid applications to assist with character creation, but many/most GMs in my experience are happy to help outside play session time; this is usually considered a good idea even with experienced, fully able players, to ensure the characters fit the campaign.

Answer (score 21):

## It shouldn't be a problem at all.

I've played a lot through the Internet in the last few years with a variety of groups, mostly as a GM. My experience mostly comes from WFRP2, which is while not the most rule-heavy system, but still very much a traditional RPG. So to address your concerns.

#### Not being able to read the rules on the fly

Not a problem, it is the GMs job to know the rules, and I've met a lot of players who prefer playing instead of book-crunching. Also, if one plays in multiple, different systems the small details tend to be forgotten, as one cares about the rules that affect his/her character. So don't worry about it, GMs have to explain to rules to a lot of players. It is faster and easier to everybody if they do and the players don't spend a lot of time with reading the rulebook.

#### Getting new information through the narrator

It is the traditional way for everybody, and depending on the group this is the only way to get new info, especially if the GM is lazy and doesn't like to prepare handouts/maps. It is important that you talk with the GM before you start playing, you might not enjoy a campaign with intricate battle-maps and tactical combat as much as a more social/cinematic playstyle.

#### Dice

It is generally useful (and through the Internet it is fairly simple) to sit down with the GM before you start playing where she/he can explain the basic rules. Setting up a Skype/Hangouts/Teamspeak/whatever call is much easier than meeting up somewhere. I strongly advise you to do this when you find a GM. Once you know what dice to roll, online games use dice-rollers, and while I don't know how accessible they are to the visually impaired, rolling should be possible and I think you can trust the others to tell you the results.

#### How to get started

I sadly can't give any advice in this, unless you are Hungarian. You should check out other questions or answers.

## Conclusion

So to conclude, being visually impaired won't be a problem online for a good amount of playstyles, but you should talk with the GM before you start rolling. It might be worth to check out different dice-rollers (roll20, rolz.org, etc) to find the easiest to use, but that is not an insurmountable problem. Find a nice GM and you are golden.

Comment: Upvoting this over others because it lists actual experience doing this.

Comment: @T.E.D. Does it? I see lots of great experience running online games for people who don't know the rules that well and don't want to slow down gameplay by thumbing through the books every two minutes. I don't see anything specific about visually impaired folks, though.

Answer (score 16):

I have a little experience with this, having been part of a D&D 3.5 campaign with a visually impaired player, who was not formerly sighted, for a couple of years. This was some time ago, but I believe they used a braille display and screen reader software to navigate character sheets and rules and the game was played face-to-face rather than online.

My experience is that an eagerness to learn/participate on the part of the VI player and a willingness to assist with descriptions and rules on the part of the others was sufficient. If you have a cooperative group then everything else will fall into place.

D&D 3.5 has rather strict combat mechanics which play out over a grid and this made thing a little bit awkward on occasion. It was necessary to carefully describe the relative locations of players, creatures and items as well as the shape and size of the spaces we were in which was a little foreign to most of the players as we were used to just using hand-drawn maps and placing miniatures, but we quickly adapted.

Whilst this generally worked out fine, we had a LOT of near misses and a few near hits from unexpectedly large Fireballs! This may have been more down to the player character's rather carefree, yet aggressive, use of magic rather than any mechanical issues however.

Long story short - yes you can, just be careful with your area of effect spells!

Answer (score 14):

The overwhelming answer, is yes you can. However, and I'm surprised nobody else mentioned this, please choose your group carefully. As with any group of people, there are bound to be a few rotten apples. I'm sure you've encountered at least a few people who have treated you poorly for your lack of vision. As wrong as it is, there are definitely people in the hobby who would subject you to more of the same. Most people in the hobby are pretty nice, (though many are somewhat naive) so it shouldn't be too hard to find a good bunch. Just avoid getting stuck with a jerk if you can.

In particular, try to find a game host (the person organizing the event, regardless the system or their title) who is very patient and is good at teaching newbies. Someone who is confident and cares about the people at their table. If they are experienced with the system, all the better. Try to get to know the person in charge of the group a little bit before you commit to any sort of game. The last thing any new gamer needs is a stream of ignorance spilling out at them while they're trying to have fun learning a new game.

And of course, if it isn't fun, you are not obligated to keep playing. Bad play is worse than no play at all.

Comment: Adding to this, be sure to find a GM who's willing to put his/her foot down if another player starts being a jerk. A kind/patient GM is no good if they let a jerk player walk all over the other players!

Answer (score 12):

### “I don't want to always be the person the GM has to explain things to.”

Other answers have given what I’d consider some good, general encouragement. But you’ve specifically stated that what you don’t want is to be the one person other folks need to “help out,” so this answer provides tips to keep that from happening.

#### Make sure the game you choose has rules in digital format

A given role-playing game may have all, some, or none of its rules available in digital format, accessible to your screen reader. The ones with [all the rules available](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/5-tabletop-rpgs-you-can-download-for-free-muo-gaming/) would be ideal, of course.  There’s no need to overdo this, but you can become as familiar as you like with the rules before you begin.

#### Know your character well

This is good advice for anyone, but many folks never do it. Everyone should know the basic statistics your character will use most. A little extra time and you can put everything about a simple character to memory. If you do, you’ll be *faster* than others at your table, who have to check their character sheets.

#### Find a “Theater of the Mind” campaign

While some groups role-play with a physical or virtual map, others eschew this, and rely entirely on the descriptions of the game master to determine where things are and what can be done. Favor these theater-of-the-mind groups if you never want to worry about moving your token or mini to the needed place.

#### If you are going to use a game play app like roll20, learn its macro system, or find someone who knows it

A couple years ago, roll20 introduced character sheets, which were a great advance for many, since many of the rolls you needed to make were now “just a click away.” But this was in some ways a step backward for accessibility, because you have to be able to read the character sheet to use it effectively.

Macros, on the other hand, let you do the same thing with a few keystrokes.

#### Brailled Dice

A group that rolls its own dice should not be a blocker for you. There are [braille dice](https://www.google.com/?client=safari#q=buy%20braille%20polyhedral%20dice) that have been well-received, as well as large, high contrast dice for those with impaired visual acuity.

#### Play to your strengths

If you’re funny, likable, organized, attentive, creative, tactical, etc., you’ll be an asset to any gaming table you join. These are the important things for a role-playing game.

Best of luck, I think you’ve got a lot of fun ahead of you.

Comment: In this situation, I think an online dice roller would be better than braille dice. OP suggested https://dicelog.com/dice which apparently works well with screen readers.

Comment: @DoktorJ, I don’t disagree about dice rollers. But I do think that braille dice were worth mentioning. Which to use, and when, may come down to personal preference.

Comment: in video chat (which OP explicitly referenced), rolling the braille dice in such a way that they would be visible to the GM and other players would be awkward/difficult, at best. Braille dice are worth a mention though for any visually impaired gamers interested in an in-person tabletop game!

Comment: I’ve DM’d games with (normal) real dice and video chat. We used the honor system for dice rolls. No problem, as long as Mr. Cheaterpants isn’t playing.

Answer (score 7):

**YES!** You can totally play voice RPGs. The GM has to explain stuff to everyone, that's just a given. If the GM is really good, then they know how to incorporate rules and rolls into gameplay so that it's not annoying.

---

As for dice, you can purchase 6 sided dice that have bumps instead of indents. I haven't yet looked for dice of different side amounts because I play *Champions or Heroes* and this game system only uses 6 sided dice.

I am in a group with a fellow who was visually impaired and is now blind. He has a great memory for his character attributes and the GM is open to reminding him what he needs to roll in the moment. We play via Skype as we all do not live in the same town. As mentioned in other posts, storytelling and creating the world or even outer space is the best part of role-playing games. Fun is the first rule!

Possible tip on homemade 20 sided dice (or whatever number sided dice). Use the puffy paint product for creating your own bumps, just fill in the dots on the regular dice. The 6-sided dice are larger and have ridges around the sides so that the bumps don't wear out too quickly or get damaged, that's where you would need to get more creative with making your own. You would find the puffy paint under the "bumps" section of an accessibility store.